# For an $n \times n$ matrix whose SVD is $A = U D V^\top$, what do we know about $UV$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd

I'm using a svd (singular value decomposition) function in a programming library that I didn't write.   Given a square real nxn matrix, svd returns three values U,S,V where S is a vector designating a diagonal matrix, and U and V are both nxn matrices.

I was expecting to find that $U\times V=I$, but I find that is not the case.

What do we know about $U\times V$ in the singular value decomposition?

What is the name of a decomposition I can search for which gives me $XDX^{-1}$ ?

Comment: I edited a bit. Please edit the rest. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: The matrix $UV^T$ is the orthogonal matrix from the [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition), which is related to the [orthogonal Procrustes problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem). If $A$ is positive definite, then $UV^T$ is the identity matrix. I don't know if there's anything special about the product $UV$, though.